# How to update data in Django when getting unique field error

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

first thing first I'm sorry for my bad english. I hope so u can understand me easily.
I'm trying to make a blog with django but there's a place I can't solve. I used unique slug field instead of id for url, whenever I want to update the data I get the UNIQUE constraint failed: post_post.url_text error (url_text is slugfield variable name). Here is the my model,

[image]

and the Form looks like this,

[image]

At first I followed a way to update the data here:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def post_update(request, url_text=None):
post = get_object_or_404(Post, url_text=url_text)
form = PostWrite(request.POST or None, instance=post)

if form.is_valid():
    post_author = request.user
    post_title = form.cleaned_data.get('post_title')
    post_content = form.cleaned_data.get('post_content')
    post_tags = form.cleaned_data.get('tags')
    post = Post(post_author=post_author, post_title=post_title, post_content=post_content, tags=post_tags)
    post.save()
    

context = {
    'post': post,
    'form': form,
}

return render(request, 'post/re_write.html', context)
```

and I got the error I mentioned at the beginning of the post. Then I found a solution like this in the forums,

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

This time it does not give any error but does not update the data. Despite hours of research, for some reason I could not find a tangible solution. I wanted to ask you esteemed coders as a last resort and I look forward to your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're creating a new post with the following code while this view appears to be an update:

```
post = Post(post_author=post_author, post_title=post_title, post_content=post_content, tags=post_tags)
post.save()
```

Instead, you should utilize the modelform you're already using to save the changes to the instance:

```
if form.is_valid():
    post = form.save()
```

I'm guessing maybe because you weren't capturing the post from `form.save()` the rendered template appeared to not have the data updated because the instance passed into the template was from before the changes.

**Other issue:**

You're overriding the save method, but not always calling `super().save`. This means that you're only saving the post when the `url_text` property is not set. Instead always call `super().save`

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if ...
       # other stuff
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: If form.is_valid ():
          post = form.save ()
          print (post.post_content)

I tried this code and saw the content coming to the terminal but it still doesn't update the data. Maybe I need to override the save command?

Comment: That sounds like the data isn't being included in the POST. You can verify that the data is being supplied by checking the request in your browser's dev tools network panel.

Comment: And can this view only be used on `POST` requests or is it valid for `GET`s as well?

Comment: I looked at the developer tools and I can see that it is implementing the post method, it returned 302 as a status code with the new data information it needs to update. do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Tufan I updated my answer to also include a fix for the model's save method.

Comment: While I was talking to you, I was a little suspicious of this situation, but I still had no clue how to do it. It is now updating the post. You're the best! thank you